# Finding poisson distribution from data set in Java

Tags: java, statistics

I have large data set in excel. I want to find out whether the numbers follow [Poisson Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) or [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) in Java. Is there any open source library that would help me to get this done. I'm looking at Apache Common Math.

Any pointers would help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a (relatively simple) model fitting problem, and you are trying to choose between two distributions. The way that you would usually do this is as follows.

1. [Estimate parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Parameter_estimation) `p_poisson` for the Poisson distribution on your data
2. [Estimate parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/estimator-for-a-binomial-distribution) `p_binomial` for the binomial distribution on your data.
3. Compute `p(data | p_poisson)` and `p(data | p_binomial)` (the likelihood function) and choose the one that has higher probability.

For more generality, I would recommend looking at [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), [BIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), and general information on [model selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection). In this case, if you don't have a ton of data, the binomial distribution should be penalized slightly for the possibility of overfitting, because it has more parameters than the Poisson.